# Scheme insertion sort without using primitive functions (car, cdr, cons)

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to write function for insertion sort with and without primitive functions.

My code with primitive functions is below.

```
(define (insert n d)
  (cond ((null? n) d)
        ((null? d) n)
        (else (< (car n) (car d)) (cons (car n) (insert (cdr n) d)) (cons (car d) (insert (cdr d) n)))))

(define (sort n)
  (cond ((null? n) '())
        (else (insert (list (car n)) (sort (cdr n))))))
```

How should I revise insert and sort to not use car, cdr, and cons?

Edit: I tried to write the insert function. This is what I have so far.

```
(define (insert n d)
  (let ((rest-digit (truncate (/ n 10))))
    (if (null? n) 0
        (+ rest-digit (insert (- n 1) d)))))

(insert '(3 2 1) '5)
```

Edit #2: I think I can use the built-in function expt.

Comment: You need to design your own data representation that doesn't use the built-in `pair` data. For instance, represent them using closures.

Comment: @Barmar What are closures?

Comment: Functions with a saved environment.

Comment: Is this an exercise from a class or tutorial? I'd expect that it would have taught that before giving this problem.

Comment: I would recommend that you first fix your existing implementation. (You have `(sort '(1 2 3))` --> `'(3 1 2)`.

Comment: How are the contract requirements? Can `n` be a data structure that holds elements chosen by you or are you damned to take `(or pair? null?)`? Are functions/forms that ultimately use `cons`,`car`, and ,`cdr` allowed?  eg. `map` is implemented with `car`, `cdr`, and `cons` so I guess it is off limits?

Comment: @Sylwester I think we can use let.

Comment: @katcsc You didn't answer my question. `let` is neither an accessor nor constructor and you cannot replace `car` with `let`. From your update you are passing a quoted list to the function. Thus you actually need `car` at least indirectly to complete the task. Thus What do you mean by "without primitive functions (car, cdr, cons)". Eg. `map` most certainly is implemented using all of them so is it allowed or not?

Comment: @Sylwester I think I can use the built-in function expt.

Comment: In that case it's easy. Check if your Scheme has `list*`, `first`, and `rest`. They are the same as `cons`, `car`, `cdr` for the same arity.

Comment: @Sylwester Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you will be using primitive functions. To illustrate let me show you a trick that actually uses `cons`, `car`, and `cdr` under the hood:

```
(define (my-car lst)
  (apply (lambda (a . d) a) lst))

(define (my-cdr lst)
  (apply (lambda (a . d) d) lst))

(define (my-cons a d)
  (apply (lambda l l) a d))


(define test (my-cons 1 '(2 3)))
test          ; ==> (1 2 3)
(my-car test) ; ==> 1
(my-cdr test) ; ==> (2 3)
```

This abuses the fact that `apply` takes a list as the final arguments and that rest arguments are `cons`-ed onto a list in order. `cons` doesn't work for all pairs:

```
(my-cons 1 2) ; ERROR: expected list?, got 1
```

You can make `cons`, `car`, and `cdr` such that they adher to the same rules as primitive `cons`, but that they are not made of pairs at all. Barmar suggested closures:

```
(define (ccons a d)
  (lambda (f) (f a d))

(define (ccar cc)
  (cc (lambda (a d) a)))

(define (ccdr cc)
  (cc (lambda (a d) d)))

(define test2 (ccons 1 2))
test2        ; ==> #<function...>
(ccar test2) ; ==> 1
(ccdr test2) ; ==> 2
```

This works since `a` and `d` gets closed over in the returned function and that function passes those values and thus the function acts as an object with two attributes. The challenge with this is that you cannot just pass a list since only "lists" made with `ccons` will work with `ccar` and `ccdr`.

A less classical way is to use vectors:

```
(define vtag (make-vector 0))
(define (vcons a d)
  (let ((v (make-vector 3)))
    (vector-set! v 0 vtag)
    (vector-set! v 1 a)
    (vector-set! v 2 d)
    v))

(define (vcar vl)
  (vector-ref vl 1))

(define (vcdr vl)
  (vector-ref vl 2))

(define (vpair? vl)
  (eq? vtag (vector-ref vl 0)))
```

Or you can use [records](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-136/srfi-136.html):

```
(define-record-type :rpair
  (rcons a d)
  rpair?
  (a rcar)
  (d rcdr))

(define test (rcons 1 2))
(rpair? test) ; ==> #t
(rcar test)   ; ==> 1
(rcdr test)   ; ==> 2
```

Now I think records just syntax sugar and abstractions and that under the hood you are doing exactly the same as the vector version with less code, but that isn't a bad thing.

**EDIT**

So from the comments if the only restriction is to avoid `car`, `cdr`, and `cons`, but no restrictions on their sisters we might as well implement with them:

```
(define (sort lst)
  (define (insert e lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        (list e)
        (let ((a (first lst)))
          (if (>= a e)
              (list* e lst)
              (list* a (insert e (rest lst)))))))

  (foldl insert
         '()
         lst))

(sort '(1 5 3 8 5 0 2))
; ==> (0 1 2 3 5 5 8)
```

And of course my first suggestion works in its place:

```
(define (sort lst)
  (define (my-car lst)
    (apply (lambda (a . d) a) lst))

  (define (my-cdr lst)
    (apply (lambda (a . d) d) lst))

  (define (my-cons a d)
    (apply (lambda l l) a d))

  (define (insert e lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        (my-cons e '())
        (let ((a (my-car lst)))
          (if (>= a e)
              (my-cons e lst)
              (my-cons a (insert e (my-cdr lst)))))))

  (foldl insert
         '()
         lst))
```

And of course, using substitution rules you can make it utterly ridiculous:

```
(define (sort lst)
  ;; insert element e into lst in order
  (define (insert e lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        ((lambda l l) e)
        (let ((a (apply (lambda (a . d) a) lst)))
          (if (>= a e)
              (apply (lambda l l) e lst)
              (apply (lambda l l)
                     a
                     (insert e (apply (lambda (a . d) d) lst)))))))

  ;; main loop of sort
  ;; insert every element into acc
  (let loop ((lst lst) (acc '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (loop (apply (lambda (a . d) d) lst)
              (insert (apply (lambda (a . d) a) lst)
                      acc)))))
```

Comment: I'm trying to write insert and sort functions without using car, cdr, and cons.

Comment: @katcsc Yes. And I suggest you can do that with one of the models/methods in my answer. They have different pros and cons but ultimately they are working around your requirement since you need a way to store elements in order to sort them. If I told you should pour water from the lake onto the fire without using a bucket you'd ultimately replace the bucket with something that can hold water.  You probably need to edit your question with what would be allowed to use since I can't think of anyway to access the first element of a `pair` that does not involve `car` in one way or another.